# jqueryui combo box renders correctly on ie8 when run from vs dev server but hidden behind another combobox when run from web server

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, combobox, webserver

this forum has been of great help so far and i havent had to ask a question till today. i have a weird issue. i am running a cascading dropdown using jquery ui from 
country->segment->competitor. everything was working per plan when i was running it directly from visual studio (both IE8 and FF). however, when i uploaded website to my iis5.1 (xp), the website still runs as expected on FF but my country dropdown gets hidden behind the segment dropdown. here are the images. i am not sure if its a z-index issue specific to ie8- the reason being it should have the same rendering whether it is run on vs dev environment or from a web server. any help is very much appreciated. 
i am unable to post images here as i am a newbie but here's a close example (the root cause here being z-index unlike my case)
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_zindex

Answer (score 0):

just to close this open question, the problem was with the IE rendering in compatibiliity mode. adding the meta code to let the browser know my website is compatible with IE8 solved my problem....